# mysql drop foreign key without table copy

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, alter-table

I have an InnoDB table `claims` which has about 240 million rows. The table has a foreign key constraint: `CONSTRAINT FK78744BD7307102A9 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES claim_details (ID)`. I want to delete the table `claim_details` as quickly as possible.

Based on some experimentation it seems that if I use `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` drop `claim_details` and then re-enable foreign keys, mysql will continue to enforce the constraint even though the table no longer exists. So, I believe I must drop the constraint from the table.

I have tried to use `ALTER TABLE claims DROP FOREIGN KEY FK78744BD7307102A9` to drop the constraint and the query has been in a state of "copy to tmp table" for over 24 hours (on a machine with no other load). I don't understand why dropping a constraint requires making a copy of the table. Is there any way to prevent this?

mysql version 5.1.48.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no a good way to drop that foreign key

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-create-index-limitations.html

"MySQL 5.5 does not support efficient creation or dropping of FOREIGN KEY constraints. Therefore, if you use ALTER TABLE to add or remove a REFERENCES constraint, the child table is copied, rather than using Fast Index Creation." This probably refers also to older versions of mysql.

I think the best method will be to dump data from `claims` with `mysqldump`, recreate table without foreign key referencing to `claim_details`, disable key check with `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` in case you have other foreign keys and import back data for `claims`. Just remember to make separate dumps for data and structure so you don't need to edit this huge file to remove foreign key from table creation syntax.

Comment: I do not want to drop the claims table. Only the claim_details table which the foreign key points to.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with MySQL 5.6, MySQL supports dropping of foreign keys in-place/without copying. Oracle calls this *Online DDL*.

This [table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html#innodb-online-ddl-summary-grid) lists all *Online DDL* operations and their runtime behavior.

From my experience, dropping foreign keys and the corresponding constraints on a 600GB table is almost instantaneous. With 5.5 it would probably have taken days.

The only disadvantage that I am aware of is, that 5.6 does not allow you to reclaim table space. I.e. if you are using `innodb_file_per_table`, that file will not shrink when you drop indices. Only the *unused data* in the file will grow. You can easily check using [SHOW TABLE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-table-status.html), and the `Data_free` column.